# Aplicación en Pygame se congela en medio de la ejecución

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

durante estos días he estado trabajando en un proyecto con Pygame, al comienzo de la aplicación el usuario debe ingresar ciertos valores que serán utilizados luego por ciertas formulas matemáticas, al ejecutar la aplicación, funciona correctamente pero solo hasta la mitad, luego se congela hasta que termina de ejecutarse la animación.

Solo me ocurre cuando defino esas variables como entradas, pero si les doy un valor fijo la aplicación no se detiene.

Adjunto mi código:

```
from math import *
import pygame, time
from pygame.constants import KEYDOWN, K_SPACE
from random import randint #Este randint lo importé solo para probar la variación de las posiciones del blanco

# ////////////// FUNCIONES //////////////
def vx(vel, rad):
# Calculo el coseno en radianes para que de esta forma el resultado lo devuelva en grados, ya que estas funciones trabajan al revés
    coseno = cos(rad)
    movX = vel*coseno
    return movX

def vy(vel, rad):
    seno = sin(rad)
    movY = vel*seno
    return movY

# ////////////// ENTRADAS ////////////////
#Probé poner las entradas antes de que iniciara la ejecución de pygame, pero tampoco funcionó
# ////////////// INICIO ///////////////
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('COYOTE MASTER KILLER')

#Estas son las entradas
x_correc = int(input('Indique la coordenada X del correcaminos, entre 550 y 800 para no tener problemas: '))
y_correc = int(input('Indique la coordenada Y del correcaminos, entre 550 y 620 para no tener problemas: '))
velocidadL= int(input('Indique la velocidad con la que quiere que se lance el proyectil: '))

# ///////////////// MÚSICA /////////////////

pygame.mixer.music.load(r'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Universidad/Introducción a la programación/Proyecto/imagenes/1.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

# ////////////// VENTANA ////////////////
# Definimos la ventana con el tiempo
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))
reloj = pygame.time.Clock()

# ////////////// IMÁGENES //////////////// 

# Importamos la imagen de fondo
fondo = pygame.image.load((r'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Universidad/Introducción a la programación/Proyecto/imagenes/fondo.png')).convert()

# Importamos la imágen del cañón
cañon = pygame.image.load((r'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Universidad/Introducción a la programación/Proyecto/imagenes/CAÑON.png')).convert_alpha()

# Importamos la imágen del misil

misil_ruta = pygame.image.load((r'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Universidad/Introducción a la programación/Proyecto/imagenes/misil.png')).convert_alpha()
misil = pygame.transform.scale(misil_ruta,(70,40))

# Importamos la ruta del título y cambiamos dimensiones (imágen)
titulo_ruta = pygame.image.load((r'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Universidad/Introducción a la programación/Proyecto/imagenes/TITULO.png')).convert_alpha()
titulo = pygame.transform.scale(titulo_ruta,(300,200))

# Importamos la ruta del coyote y cambiamos sus dimensiones (imágen)
coyote_ruta = pygame.image.load((r'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Universidad/Introducción a la programación/Proyecto/imagenes/coyote.png')).convert_alpha()
coyote = pygame.transform.scale(coyote_ruta,(275,175))

# Importamos la ruta del correcaminos y cambiamos sus dimensiones (imágen)
corre_ruta =pygame.image.load((r'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/Universidad/Introducción a la programación/Proyecto/imagenes/correcaminos.png')).convert_alpha()
correcaminos = pygame.transform.scale(corre_ruta,(200,175))

# ////////////// VARIABLES ////////////////

posCañon = 170,700 #Posicion x,y del cañón
posMisil_X = 170 #Esta es una constante debido a ello tendré dos variables para x del misil y dos para y, una constante y otra que variará con el tiempo
posMisil_Y = 700 #Constante en y
contador = 0 #Este contador se utilizará mas adelante como medidor de segundos
corPosX = 0  # Defino esta variable antes solo para que el ciclo inicie y se entienda su contenido
corPosY = 0 # Defino esta variable antes solo para que el ciclo inicie y se entienda su contenido

#La puntuación será mayor entre mas cerca haya caído el proyectil del blanco
puntuacion = 0

# ////////////// EVENTOS ////////////////
done = False
while not done:

# ////////////// LÓGICA GRADUAL ////////////////
#Obtengo la posicion del raton del usuario, de esta forma mido los grados antes, para no tener que
#escribir más variables
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x = x/6
    grados = 85-x
    #Limito los grados a 30 y 85 para que el usuario no pueda disparar tan facil al correcaminos ni se pueda disparar a si mismo
    if grados < 30:
        grados = 85-55 

# ////////////// EVENTOS 2 ////////////////
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True     
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                # Transformo los grados a radianes para no tener problemas con las funciones de "math"
                radianA = radians(grados)
                # Llamada a las funciones
                velX= vx(velocidadL,radianA) #Velocidad en x
                velY = vy(velocidadL,radianA) #Velocidad en y
                #Minetras la cordenada de posicion en y sea menor o igual a 701 con 700 como suelo         
                while corPosY <= 701:
                    #Volvemos a dibujar para ir eliminando el misil del fondo
                    ventana.blit(fondo, [0, 0])
                    ventana.blit(titulo,[300,-50])
                    ventana.blit(misil_mov, misil_rect)
                    ventana.blit(cañon_mov, cañon_rect)
                    ventana.blit(coyote, [0,600,])
                    ventana.blit(correcaminos, [x_correc,y_correc]) 
                    #inicializamos el contador que se utulizará como el referente tiempo
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    contador += 1 #Si este número lo hacemos más pequeño los saltos entre distancias serán más pequeños.
                    #Fórmulas dadas 
                    corPosX = round(posMisil_X + velX * contador)
                    corPosY = round(posMisil_Y + velY * contador - 4.9 * contador ** 2)
                    #Realizo esta operación para que la posicion del misil calze en el tamaño de la ventana
                    corPosY = (800-corPosY)+500
                    # Dibjo el misil por pantalla y actualizo la ventana
                    ventana.blit(misil_mov, (corPosX,corPosY))
                    pygame.display.update()
                if (x_correc - 100) <= corPosX <= (x_correc + 100):
                    puntuacion += 10
                    
# ////////////// LÓGICA 2 ////////////////
#  ********* Movimiento del cañón **********

    cañon_mov = pygame.transform.rotate(cañon,grados)
    cañon_rect = cañon_mov.get_rect()
    cañon_rect.center = posCañon

#  ********* Movimiento misil **********
    misil_mov = pygame.transform.rotate(misil, grados)
    misil_rect = misil_mov.get_rect()
    misil_rect.center = (posMisil_X,posMisil_Y)

# ********* PINTAMOS ELEMENTOS EN VENTANA *********    
# Esto se utiliza cuando el usuario no a presionado la tecla SPACE
    #Fondo
    ventana.blit(fondo, [0, 0])
    # Título 
    ventana.blit(titulo,[300,-50])
    # Misil
    ventana.blit(misil_mov, misil_rect)
    # Cañón
    ventana.blit(cañon_mov, cañon_rect)
    # Coyote
    ventana.blit(coyote, [0,600,])
    # Correcaminos 
    ventana.blit(correcaminos, [x_correc,y_correc]) 
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    reloj.tick(60) 

pygame.quit()
```

Aún tengo que corregir algunas cosas en el código pero lo ideal sería resolver este bug antes.
Si alguien tiene una idea de que es lo que puede estar fallando me podría decir, se lo agradecería mucho.

Estoy dispuesto a probar cada uno de sus consejos.

Comment: hace mucho tiempo que no trabajo con Pygame, pero intenta definir los *inputs* antes de inicializar *PyGame*

Comment: ¿y cómo esperas obtener el seno coseno y radianes sin importar la biblioteca math?